# run a function before and after specific Celery tasks?

Tags: python, celery

I am looking to run a function before a celery task executes as well as a function after the task completes. However, I only want to do this for **specific** tasks. Therefore, I don't think [celery signals](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html?highlight=signals#task-signals) task_prerun will work for me?

What is the correct way to run a function before and after **specific** Celery tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply add a separate parameter say `perform_func` and if it is true, you execute the functions. If you can not change the function signature, then, create a global state and store the functions in it.

Example:

```py
def execute_before():
    print("before task")

def execute_after():
    print("after task")
```

Here are the below approaches.

1. As a function parameter

```py
@task(name="your_task")
def your_task(perform_func=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if perform_func:
        execute_before()
    # Your task logic
    ...
    if perform_func:
        execute_after()
```

2. As a global state

```py
STATE = [your_task]

@task(name="your_task")
def your_task(*args, **kwargs):
    if your_task in STATE:
        execute_before()
    # Your task logic
    ...
    if your_task in STATE:
        execute_after()
```

**EDIT**

Upon rethinking, I feel there is yet another way. You can make a global task handler and pass all requests through it.

```py
@task(name="global_handler")
def global_handler(func: Callable, perform_func=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if perform_func:
        execute_before()
    func() # call as a normal function
    if perform_func:
        execute_after()

def your_task(*args, **kwargs):
    # Your task logic
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # task caller function
    global_handler.delay(your_task, True)
```

This trick comes with a cost. If you are say storing the task status in some database or having it as logs, all your entries will essentially have the same task name which would make segregating tasks difficult. You can obviously segregate that by the argument passed but it will be much harder to do a query on that. On the plus side, this method absolutely follows DRY principles.